# How to get a list of feed items from a Query Document Snapshot?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I have tried both the codes below: One with StreamBuilder.ListView and other StreamBuilder.ListView.builder. I couldn't get a result. It shows

> The method 'data' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling:
> data()

I am not able to get how QuerySnapshots work

```
class FeedStream extends StatelessWidget {
  FeedStream();
  Map document;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 2,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.docs[index]);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(document.data()['displayName']),
      subtitle: Text(document.data()['bio']),
    );
  }
}



class FeedStream extends StatelessWidget {
  FeedStream();
  Map document;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return ListView(
            children: snapshot.data.docs.map((document) {
              return Center(
                child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
                  child:
                      Text('Name:' + document.data()['displayName'].toString()),
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that there are two documents:

```
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 2, // HERE
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.docs[index]);
    },
  );
```

But that's not always the case, and when there are fewer than 2 documents you get the error that you're seeing.

The solution is to return the item count that corresponds to the number of documents in the query snapshot:

```
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount:, snapshot.data.docs.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.docs[index]);
    },
  );
```

Comment: Hi Frank van Puffelen. Thanks for the answer. I tried it again. It's still shows the same error

Answer (score 0):

StreamBuilder have a property called initialData. You can try giving it an empty list.

Example:

```
StreamBuilder<T>(
         initialData: [], 
         stream: _myStream,
         builder: _myBuilder,
);
```